# Check the current Row is a data row or not

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a gridview with 10 rows i am displaying 6 rows in each page i have a text box and and image button in each row when i click the image button all the functionalities are working but when i click the page index it is displaying an error in row command how can i check whether the row type is data row or not in gridview row command event. the code that i am using is as follows

```
protected void gvgridview1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
      GridViewRow gvRow = (GridViewRow)(((ImageButton)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer);
      TextBox txtgvGroupName = (TextBox)gvRow.FindControl("txtgvGroupName");
      ImageButton imgbtn = (ImageButton)gvRow.FindControl("imgbtn");
      if (e.CommandName == "Edit")
            {
              imgbtn.Visible = false;
            }
    }
```

Comment: You should post what error you're getting. I'm guessing you're getting error because of (ImageButton)e.CommandSource where your index link is not ImageButton.

Answer (score 3):

If(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)

then write your condition.

Answer (score 1):

a little to do with the datarow here, instead you need to check `if (e.CommandSource is ImageButton)` at the first line of your `gvgridview1_RowCommand`

Comment: yes that works fine thanks for your help the follwing code is working fine   string strTemp = string.Empty;
        strTemp = e.CommandSource.ToString();
        if (strTemp == "System.Web.UI.WebControls.ImageButton")
        {

Comment: I thought you can just use `if (e.CommandSource is ImageButton)` ?

Comment: Good to hear from you yes that too works thanks i am using is for the first time.. Thanks once again

Comment: @Mathew, I'm glad you have solved your problem, please mark the answer as accepted if that was the case.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried checking the RowType property of the GridViewRow instance?

Comment: Well, that's strange. According to this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewrow.rowtype.aspx  the GridViewRow has that property.

Comment: i am telling you that in the Gridview_RowCommand there is no property like e.rowtype

Comment: That's not what I'm telling you. In your code you have an instance of GridViewRow (gvRow), doesn't that object have that property?

Answer (score 0):

Check `e.Row.RowType`, it allows you to compare the RowType to the `DataControlRowType` enum.

[EDIT] I wonder if it's something to do with how you're getting hold of the row. The code I just tried is:

```
GridViewRow row = Gridview.Rows[int.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString())];
```

After that I can use `row.RowType` quite happliy. Might be worth a try for you.

[DataControlRowType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datacontrolrowtype.aspx)

Comment: @Mathew Just updated my answer with something you might want to try

Comment: Fails if you are using sorting, since the commandArgument for Sort is the SortExpression.

Answer (score 0):

try this assuming you are reffering System.Data.DataRow

```
GridViewRow gvRow = (GridViewRow)(((ImageButton)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer);
DataRow drow = gvRow.DataItem as DataRow

if(drow!=null)
 {
     // row is DataRow
 }
```

Comment: my code is working fine the problem happens when i click the gridview page index to view the next page other times my page is working fine